# Sql Server 2019 Query Hint Placement confusion

Tags: query-performance, sql-server-2019, hints

I'm using SQL Server 2019 (CU4) and I'm encountering some strange issues when trying to use a query hint for the legacy cardinality estimation due to a poorly performing Table Value Function.  I'm not sure whether I can create a minimal verifiable example of my problem, but I wanted to put this question out in case anyone else has encountered this issue.  Consider the following query selecting rows from a temp table and invoking a TVF (`dbo.AccountHasHomeownerPolicy`):

```
SELECT ST.MONTH_END_DATE
      ,ST.RUN_DATE
      ,ST.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
      ,ST.POLICY_CONTROL
      ,ST.LOB
      ,ST.POLICY_NUMBER
      ,ST.DEC_AMEND
         ,ST.TRANSACTION_LUW
      ,ST.ITEM
        ,HO_EXISTS = AccountHasHomeownerPolicy.AccountHasHomeownerPolicy
      ,AGENCY_HO_EXISTS =
        (CASE 
             WHEN EXISTS
            (SELECT 'Y' 
           FROM [SCSQLPC].[dbo].MIP_AUS_POL_WRITEN APW
          WHERE APW.LOB='AU'
            AND APW.POLICY_NUMBER=ST.POLICY_NUMBER
            AND APW.LOB_WRITTEN='AH'
            AND APW.EFFECTIVE_DATE.Date=ST.EFFECTIVE_DATE)
          THEN 'Y'
          ELSE 'N'
          END
        )
  FROM #INFORCETABLE ST
  OUTER APPLY dbo.AccountHasHomeownerPolicy
   (ST.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,ST.EFFECTIVE_DATE) AccountHasHomeownerPolicy
   OPTION (USE HINT ('FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION'))
```

In my testing, I always issue `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` before each test run. (I on an isolated test server)

When I specify the HINT, I can display an *estimated execution plan* which shows everything using the legacy estimator.  However, when I actually run the query and then run `sp_blitzcache` in another window, the plan that is generated is using cardinality estimation of 150 (SQL 2019) and the query performs poorly.

If a remove the query hint from the main query and put it in the actual TVF, the plan that is generated (as seen from `sp_blitzcache`) shows the TVF using the legacy cardinality estimator and the query performs quickly.

My expectation would be that the query hint placed at the bottom of the main query (and without any additional query hints) would be in effect for all processes involved for that query, but that does not appear to be happening in this case.